# Please confirm character limit/ length for What's new section for Apple Appstore in iTunes Connect

Tags: app-store

I need to know the number of characters that can be put in the Appstore listing, What's New section.

I understand can get this from the AppStore Connect if I try to create a new version. However, I'm not able to do this right now, and cannot seem to find anywhere where the character limits are documented.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the policies and procedures of app distribution services, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The limit for what's new section per platform is:

Android: 500
iOS: 4000

Comment: Would be nice if you also provided the source.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't find official documentation for this, on App Store Connect. So I did this:

[image]

There you go.